# Managing private NuGet package registry VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently switched to VSCode from Visual Studio 2022 and needed to manage custom NuGet packages made by my company. I want it to be somewhat similar to Visual Studio 2022's NuGet Package manager.

This is what I've tried so far with no success:

1. [NuGet Gallery](https://github.com/pcislo/vscode-nuget-gallery) VSCode extension

   - I downloaded the extension and installed [CredentialProvider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) to be able to authenticate the package source
   - I added an environment variable with the suggested json format:

`{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"http://example.index.json", "username":"optional", "password":"accesstoken"}]}`

- I then added the name and url as a source from the VSCode extension settings:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXEX2.png)

2. NuGet.config file in the project directory

   - The problem here is that it does not help me manage packages easily (browsing, updating, downgrading, etc.)
3. [NuGet Package Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmrog.vscode-nuget-package-manager) VSCode extension

   - Problem here is that it has no way of configurating package registries

For information, I am using .NET 3 to 7, and the package registry is on GitLab.

Can somebody please help me fix this issue because I've looked everywhere and ran out of options?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Azure [Artifacts Credential Provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#setup) installed, then add your package sources to nuget.config.

After that, run `dotnet restore --interactive` on your project root path. You may need to copy a code from your root path and enter it in https://microsoft.com/devicelogin